# What web server is using this favicon?

Tags: website, webserver, favicon

This might seem like an odd question but I see no option but to ask it anyway. I have seen this favicon like a million times. But I just can't figure out what server uses this favicon.

It's a red circled line on a dark yellow, orange-ish kind of looking background, and then there are like three i letters centered in the middle of the circle, they kind of look like three guys standing next to each in a group hug.

Here's a screen caption of what it looks like:

[image: server favicon]

What server uses this favicon? And what's the deal with not changing the default favicon anyway?...

I did a lots of Google queries and even did a picture search as input and found nothing relevant. This is one of few moments where Google has not been able to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's Lotus Domino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every website has the ability to use whatever favicon it likes.  An IIS server could use a Tomcat icon if it wants too.  Weird, but it could.

Most web servers send back some description of themselves when requests are made.  Try out the following website:

http://uptime.netcraft.com/

At the top in the "Whats that site running?" field, enter in the domain for the site you are researching.  You should see details about the OS and server.  Of course, this could be spoofed as well, but you may get a hint.

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed a helpful tip. As it turned out, that favicon comes from the Lotus-Domino server.